# Как сделать так, чтобы document.writeln() делал перевод каретки?

Tags: javascript

```js
var str = prompt('Введите строку: ');
const numOfFirst = 0;
const numOfLast = str.length - 1;
const separator = ' ';
writeWithOutLast(str, numOfFirst, numOfLast);

function writeWithOutLast(str, numOfFirst, numOfLast) {
  document.write('Введенная строка без последнего символа: ');
  for (curr = numOfFirst; curr <= numOfLast - 1; curr++) {
    document.writeln(str.charAt(curr)); // Печатает символы в одну строку
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Символ "перевода каретки" рассматривается браузером как white-space.

```
document.writeln(str.charAt(curr), "<br/>");
```